# Does it have any value getting a PhD in engineering after 45?

Tags: phd, age

I am talking about academia and research.

Suppose, a person doesn't have either professional or academic credentials or experiences. Suddenly he decides to study engineering because he wants to change his stagnation both financially and socially. So, he enrolls in BSc in an engineering program at the age of 40. He completes his BSc at the age of 44, completes his MSc at the age of 45-47, and then completes his Ph.D. in engineering at the age of 49-55.

- Does this Ph.D. degree have any material value for this person?

There are multiple factors to think about.

Firstly, this person never had any corporate and academia related job experience. It is hard to believe that he would be able to get along with these work environments. It is generally hard to mould someone's brain and personality at the age of 40+. So, I believe that he will find hard-times finding a job.

Secondly, most people are forced to retire at the age of 65-68. If he starts his job at 49-55, he has only 16-13 years of his life left for earning money. The amount he earns with his Ph.D. is highly unlikely to compensate for the earnings he sacrificed while getting his degrees.

So, my view would be: this person is not gaining much with his Ph.D.

What do you think?

Comment: For me, there was immense value in the intellectual challenge.

Comment: Many (most?) countries have laws against age discrimination, so this person should not be at a disadvantage when applying for jobs in academia.

Comment: @astronat De facto, the laws do not change much in countries with age discrimination. But Anglo-Saxon countries are in my experience pretty good at not being age-discriminatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The amount he earns with his PhD is highly unlikely to compensate for the earnings he sacrificed while getting his degrees.

Is money the only motivation? If so, you may want to consider options between "remain a taxi driver" and "do a PhD." You may want to post on Workplace.SE for help finding the level of education that will maximize your lifetime earnings.

I would suggest, though, that there are important factors other than prestige and money. Specifically, passion for the subject matter. So, I would suggest that you should take a few CS classes before planning out the rest of your life.

> It is hard to believe that he would be able to get along with these work environments. It is generally hard to mould someone's brain and personality

I suspect you will have to overcome these challenges when earning your degrees. By the time you have a permanent position, you  will be familiar with the culture.

> taxi driver is actually a loser with or without a PhD.

Taxi drivers perform a useful service; I would certainly not call them losers. That said, you are 40 years old and therefore (hopefully) less than halfway through your life; it is too early to give up on yourself.

Comment: Isn't there lack of PhDs in CS?

Comment: @SSimon, there is nothing called "lack". No one is going to hire you unless you have proper skills.

Comment: @user366312 are you saying that some PhD don't give you any skills

Answer (score 3):

[You can answer this with salary survey data.](https://www.higheredjobs.com/salary/salaryDisplay.cfm?SurveyID=51)  Based on the data, it would be reasonable to assume a CS academic would earn $95,000/year a few years after their PhD.  This would rapidly make up for any lost earnings from not driving a taxi during a PhD, so we can determine that the answer is *yes* without figuring out the taxi driver's earnings or the PhD stipend.

Comment: While I can see the point of this answer, **do not** do a PhD for (only and if any) the monetary gain, you will regret it. Do it if you love the research subject and want to contribute to society that way.

Comment: @DimP, when a taxi driver decides to do a Ph.D. at the age of 40, he doesn't do it for the society for sure.

Comment: @user366312 Why not? When I did my PhD, one of the other cohort students (44 years old) decided to pursue a PhD for that exact reason, due to stagnation in his job as a technician. Also (is it right to assume you are talking about the US?), I know of a few European countries where you could end up earning quite a bit more as a taxi driver rather than a PhD holder.

Comment: @DimP: In my country, it was (maybe 20 years ago) not uncommon to do a phd just to be in a better position socially. I know some people who did this (mainly politicians) who do not regret it